# A(z1) B(z2) C(z3) D(z4) are four points on a circle |z| = 1 where z represents a complex number

Tags: complex-numbers

A(z <sub>1</sub> )  B(z <sub>2</sub> )  C(z <sub>3</sub> )  D(z <sub>4</sub> ) are four points on a circle |z| = 1  where z represents a complex number . Given that line AB is parallel to line CD .  Prove that z <sub>1</sub>  . z <sub>2</sub>  =  z <sub>3 .</sub>  z <sub>4</sub>

MY ATTEMPT :
I tried using the condition of concyclic points that cross product of the numbers should be real , rotation taking center as origin and condition of parallel lines in complex form  but I didn't get any break through from that

Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The segments $AB\parallel CD$ have a common median bisector which intersects the unit circle at two points; call one of them $z_*$. There are then two angles $\alpha$,  $\beta$ such that
$$z_1=e^{i\alpha}z_*\>,\quad z_2=e^{-i\alpha}z_*\>,\quad z_3=e^{i\beta}z_*\>,\quad z_4=e^{-i\beta}z_*\ .$$
It follows that $z_1z_2=z_*^2=z_3z_4$.

(By the way: It is not necessary to give each of your points two different names.)

Answer (score 0):

My attempt would be as follows.
Given four complex numbers $z_i = e^{i \theta_i}$, $ i = 1,2,3,4$.

Further, we know the lines through $z_1$, $z_2$ and $z_3$, $z_4$ are parallel.
This translates to one of the two conditions

$$\frac{\theta_1 +\theta_2}{2} = \frac{\theta_3 +\theta_4}{2}$$ or $$\frac{\theta_1 +\theta_2}{2} = \frac{\theta_3 +\theta_4}{2} + \pi $$

They reflect the fact that for the lines to be parallel, their normals through the origin must coincide. Normals directions  are computed as the average of the arguments (angles $\theta_i$) of the complex numbers through which the lines are defined.

The claim that the products

$$ z_1 z_2 = e^{i (\theta_1 + \theta_2)}$$  and
$$ z_3 z_4 = e^{i (\theta_3 + \theta_4)}$$

follows immediately if the first conditions applies.
If the second condition above applies, one notes that points on the complex circle are defined modulo a $2 \pi$ rotation.